# Javascript increment number gradually by a changing amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

the code below is a clicker game like cookie clicker but very basic, the game has an interval that increases the 'cookies' by the amount of 'autoclickers' (CPS) purchased per 300ms, and also the user can click an image to increase the 'cookies' by 1.

My problem is that the interval does not increment gradually it adds in solid chunks every 300ms, how can I get it to add to the 'cookies' smoothlymoothly one by one?

Thankyou

```
   var globals = {
    CPS: 0
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    //auto add CPS every 300ms (this is what I want to happen gradually
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#lblCookies").text(parseInt($("#lblCookies").text()) + globals.CPS);
    }, 300);

    //click the cookie to get one
    $("#imgCookie").click(function () {
        $("#lblCookies").text(parseInt($("#lblCookies").text()) + 1);
    });

   //buy an auto clicker
   $("#btnBuyAuto").click(function() {
    globals.CPS = globals.CPS + 1;
   });
});
```

Comment: Update it more frequently? Or update as a reaction to a button click as well as to the timer.

Comment: I could update more freauently but it will still increment by the CPS instead of one by one smoothly. If the CPS is 10 i don't want it to go 1-10 I want it to go 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10.

Comment: Instead of changing `CPS`, change the frequency that you update, and increment it by 1 every time.

Comment: @Danforth Add a second global: a counter that keeps track of the amount currently output. Every time the timer runs, increment it by 1 while it's less than CPS. Once the second counter is >= CPS, stop incrementing.

Comment: @Adjit globals.CPS is basically how many auto clickers they have. I want to increase the actual cookie amount $("#lblcookies") by the CPS every 300ms but gradually. so if there is 5 CPS, when the interval runs i want it to add it like this 1-2-3-4-5 instead of just straight from 1 to 5. Does that make sense?

Comment: Depending on how many auto clickers you have, something like this could work: https://jsfiddle.net/ay07oq14/

Comment: @JasonP That was exactly what I was looking for thank-you